# string to timestamp mysql Error #1411

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to convert timestamps on the fly when importing a csv file into mysql from string to datetime data type. But I am getting a `#1411 - Incorrect datetime value: '2007-03-30 16:01:15' for function str_to_date` error.

The SQL:

```
load data infile 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/data/testfile.csv'
into table test
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
(date, col1,col2,col3,col4)
SET
date = str_to_date(date,'%Y.%m.%d %H:%i:%s.%f');
```

All rows in the .csv are formated like this:

```
2007.03.30 16:01:15.901,117.53,117.55,35600000,43700000
```

I've applied

```
SELECT str_to_date(date,'%Y.%m.%d %H:%i:%s.%f') FROM test
```

to sample data that was already stored in mysql, it did work.

The target row `date` is set to `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go via a user variable.  As [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) says:

> The column list can contain either column names or user variables. With user variables, the `SET` clause enables you to perform transformations on their values before assigning the result to columns.
>
> User variables in the `SET` clause can be used in several ways. The following example uses the first input column directly for the value of `t1.column1`, and assigns the second input column to a user variable that is subjected to a division operation before being used for the value of `t1.column2`:
>
> ```
> LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
>   INTO TABLE t1
>   (column1, @var1)
>   SET column2 = @var1/100;
> ```

In your case:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/data/testfile.csv'
  INTO TABLE test
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  LINES  TERMINATED BY '\n'
  (@date, col1, col2, col3, col4)
  SET date = STR_TO_DATE(@date, '%Y.%m.%d %H:%i:%s.%f');
```

Comment: Also: the `%f` format expects six digits for the microseconds, whereas your CSV appears to contain only three; whilst you could fix that with string manipulation functions, you could remove the `%f` altogether as  in `STR_TO_DATE` [extra characters at the end of ***`str`*** are ignored](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and, in any event, [when MySQL stores a value into a column of any temporal data type, it discards any fractional part and does not store it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fractional-seconds.html).

Comment: You found out exactly what was wrong. Thanks! And also thanks for the "why".